# How do I programmatically access items in the Workbox?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

How does Sitecore find these items?  I want to set up a schedule task to email my admins when there are items pending in the Workbox.  Maybe there is already a feature like this?  The only piece of the puzzle I am missing is how to easily identify when/if Workbox items exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item is shown in the Workbox as long as it is in the workflow and not in the final state. Take a look at [this shared source component](http://trac.sitecore.net/WorkflowEscalator) - it seems to be just your requirement. [This one](http://trac.sitecore.net/SitecoreWorkboxGadget) is also quite similar.

Comment: Thanks, the description of the WorkflowEscalator seems to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sending emails when an item is in a workflow state why don't you try using the RSS feeds that Sitecore generates for each state. Details are in the [Client Configuration Cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Client%20Configuration%20Cookbook.aspx).

The majority of email clients have built in RSS readers which typically will show the feed as a separate "inbox". IMHO this is much better than email alerts which often get ignored because of how spammy they can get.

Comment: Oh Steve... you must live in a magical world where you can make decisions about actual features.  :)  I'm trying to steer our client away from the email option as well, but so far they are insisting. Thanks for the suggestion, I hadn't realized there was a built-in feature for this.